# Unable to import tkinter for Python file in VSCodium for Pop!_OS

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, vscodium

I was trying to install tkinter for my Python file so that I would be able to display a window with GUI. However I am encountering this error: `File "/home/zhenf/VSCodium_Workspace/pyfilereader/fileReader.py", line 4, in <module> import tkinter as tk ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'` when I try to run my python file in VSCodium.

I downloaded python with the command `sudo apt install python3` for my Home folder, parent folder where my project folder is located, and my project folder where my python file is stored. I have tkinter installed in my Home folder and my project folder. tkinter works fine when I run the python shell on my Pop!_OS terminal but does not work when I try to run my python file with VSCodium.

How may I be able to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: How did you install tkinter?  What was the exact command?

Comment: I installed tkinter via the terminal with `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`. I tried following tkinter docs: https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html#install-x11-python

Comment: In the terminal, you are manually running `python`. In the IDE, it's using `/bin/python3`. As far as I know, it might be possible that those 2 are different installations of python. To test it, try running `/bin/python3 --version` (check if it's 3.10.12)

Comment: What result do you get from `python --version` *at the `sh-5.2` prompt within Codium*?

Comment: When I am at my python file path and type `/bin/python3 --version`, I get `Python 3.11.7` for both VSCodium's `sh` and `python debug console`. Are my python versions part of my issue?

Comment: I noticed that when I am at my python file path and type `/bin/python3 --version`, I get `Python 3.10.12` within my terminal. Strange since VSCodium's `sh` and `python debug console` show `Python 3.11.7`.